# Merge new object in firebase database inside document

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored my data into firebase database by getting data from google sheet. The problem I am getting is every time I run the application It sets with new document Id. I want only one document in the firebase database collection.
My question is How do I merge data when I get new data object as response?
Example:

[image]

I have got following response :

```
0: {Id: 202, Name: 'word', Major: 'comp'}
1: {Id: 203, Name: 'John', Major: 'science'}
2: {Id: 204, Name: 'nsia', Major: 'cmpi'}
```

and It is stored in database.
Now when I run application again then It creates new document instead of merging new data to old document.
Example:
new data is

```
0: {Id: 205, Name: 'hello', Major: 'sci'}
```

and I want to merge object and get as

```
0: {Id: 202, Name: 'word', Major: 'comp'}
1: {Id: 203, Name: 'John', Major: 'science'}
2: {Id: 204, Name: 'nsia', Major: 'cmpi'}
3: {Id: 205, Name: 'hello', Major: 'sci'}
```

How do we do merge?
Here is my code to get data and post data

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../shared/auth.service';
import { Field } from '../model/field';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.page.scss'],
})

export class LandingPagePage implements OnInit {
  Object = Object;
  myArray: Field[] = [];
  private collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Field>;
  myCollection: any;
   constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router:Router, private http :HttpClient,private afs: AngularFirestore) { 
  this.collection = this.afs.collection<Field>("Exceldata");
   this.myCollection = this.collection.snapshotChanges(); 
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.excelData();
      this.auth.getDataFromFirebase().subscribe(myArray => {
      this.myArray = myArray;
    });
  }
logout()
{
  this.auth.signOut();
}

excelData(){
var sf = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qeCEUlVt_hnuyhnoT1wxMMSv7kZW1s4cUIRLynJ0TxQ/gviz/tq?tqx=out:json";
 this.http.get(sf,{responseType: 'text'}).subscribe(res=>{
    const data =res.toString().match(/google\.visualization\.Query\.setResponse\(([\s\S\w]+)\)/);
   if(data && data.length==2){

     const obj=JSON.parse(data[1]);
     const table=obj.table;
     const header =  table.cols.map(({label}) => label);
     const rows = table.rows.map(({c}) => c.map(({v}) => v));
     const values = rows.map(e => header.reduce((o, f, j) => Object.assign(o, {[f]: e[j]}), {}));
     console.log(values);

     if(!this.collection.doc){
         this.collection.doc().set(Object.assign({}, values));    
     }else{
         this.collection.doc().set((values),{merge: true});
     }

    }  
 });
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a better way of doing it but I've survived by storing my items locally eg as an array, appending new item and then saving as a new item.

Comment: I am looking for other way where we don't need to store locally. I found something like `this.collection.doc().set((values),{merge: true});` but it was not helpful.

Comment: Yah that doesn't work at all for some reason.